# invalid url while creating external table in snowflake

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-schema, external-tables

I want to use the external table in the snowflake and i created a table using the sql as show below

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test_stage (
    column1 datatype1,
    column2 datatype2,
)
LOCATION = '@abc.def.ghe/'
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = 'CSV' COMPRESSION = 'GZIP' FIELD_DELIMITER = ',' SKIP_HEADER = 0);
```

I have checked the access and everything is write. but it producing an error

> 'invalid url =@abc.def.ghe/'

Any thoughts

I check the access, path, storage, and URL. everything is accessible accept creating the table

Comment: Try creating a stage name that doesn't have periods in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to remove the single quotes from the url and retry.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).